# How to add css class in class

Tags: css, class

I have e very big data and i want to give class dynamically by state.

```
"<td> 
    <i class='fullPassengerListState_" + data[i].State + "'>"
     + data[i].State + "
    </i>
</td>"
```

I want this

fullPassengerListState_1 class should be fa-check (Font Awesome)

fullPassengerListState_0 class should be fa-times (Font Awesome)

I don't want to use if ( data[i].state == 0 ) or something like that.

Comment: use in your css `.fullPassengerListState_1{ content:'your icon unicode'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do it in css by pesudo `:before` to `.fullPassengerListState_1/0`:

**NOTE!**
I use to the example Font Awesome 5

```css
.fullPassengerListState_1:before{ 
  content:'\f00c';
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
}
.fullPassengerListState_0:before{ 
  content:'\f00d';
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-O8whS3fhG2OnA5Kas0Y9l3cfpmYjapjI0E4theH4iuMD+pLhbf6JI0jIMfYcK3yZ" crossorigin="anonymous">


<i class='fullPassengerListState_0'> state 0
</i>
<i class='fullPassengerListState_1'> state 1
</i>
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: Tnx its more than enough :)

Comment: happy to help:):)